# Make next js Page Component persisten / Render multiple Pages at same time

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to build an App that takes advantage of the SSG functionality of next js and shows multiple Page components at the same time. Each of the components should be static and come with their own data.

The problem is that I don't know how to persist the first Page component when the route for the second Page component is called. Putting it into state works, but according to the react docs this is not a good idea. Of course I could simply get the data out of the props for the Pages and make the client render the component but this solution doesn't exactly take advante of SSG.

I made a codesandbox that shows what I'm trying to achieve by putting the pages into the state of the Layout component:

https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-lichterman-v70zl

Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do whithout using state?
Or is using state in this way a feasible exception?
Or am I on the wrong track entirely?

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: That's not how next works. Next is opinionated about routing. What you want is something like CRA that can be more flexible here

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I suppose I would need something like 'react static' to achieve SSG with create react app?